# Cant get JQGrid loadComplete event to fire

Tags: jqgrid, jquery

I'm trying to simulate a click on the first cell after the grid is loaded. I already know how to accomplish this, but for some reason I can't get the "loadComplete" event to fire. I have added a simple function with a single alert to try it out, but even though the page loads with no problem, I'm not getting the alert (and debugging shows the function is never called).

"gridComplete" is not working either.

I am using jgGrid 3.8.2

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I have posted my code below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid(
            {
                datatype: function () {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetListOfPersons",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (jsondata, stat) {
                            if (stat == "success")
                                jQuery("#grid")[0].addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata.d));
                            else
                                alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                jsonReader:
                {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "Id"
                },
                colModel: //Columns
                [
                    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 200, align: 'Left', label: 'First Name', editable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 300, align: 'Left', label: 'Last Name', editable: true },
                    { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 50, align: 'Right', label: 'Age', editable: true }
                ],
                caption: "Personas",
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                pager: "#pager",
                loadComplete: function () { alert("load complete"); }
            }
            ).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false }).navButtonAdd('#pager',
            {
                caption: "Save",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    var ret = $("#grid").getChangedCells('dirty');
                    var ret2 = JSON.stringify(ret);
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetChangesBack",
                        data: '{"o":' + ret2 + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                    );
                },
                position: "last"
            }
            );
    }
    );
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `Default.aspx/GetListOfPersons`? It seems to me that you make JSON serialization **twice**. I suppose this because you use `JSON.parse(jsondata.d)` inside of `success` handler of `$.ajax`. If you post the code I will try to change it so, that you will be able to use jqGrid without having `datatype` as a function.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are calling `$.ajax` yourself, I don't think `loadComplete` *should* fire.

`gridComplete` should work, though.